# Using \widthof without an intermediate variable

Tags: width, lengths

I know how to get the width in pt or sp of, say, the letter x in LaTeX using the calc package:

```
\newlength{\xwidth}%
\setlength{\xwidth}{\widthof{x}}%
\the\xwidth{}, \number\xwidth sp.%
```

As a C hacker, my approach was:

```
%\number\widthof{x}
```

because in my thinking `\number` needs an argument of type length, `\widthof` delivers one, so I don't need an intermediate variable like `\xwidth` in LaTeX. I would like to know why that doesn't work.

Comment: would your C hacker expect you to supply a code block doing assignments to internal variables as an argument to printf?  But you can get the width directly from the font metrics `\number\the\fontcharwd\font `x`  will work.

Answer (score 4):

No, `\widthof{x}` doesn't return a length. If you try from a terminal

```bash
latexdef -s -p calc \widthof
```

you'll get the surprising answer

```
% calc.sty, line 118:
\let\widthof\ignorespaces
```

The `calc` package redefines `\setlength` so that it can parse expressions where `\widthof` and similar commands act as markers for subsequent computations involving box creation and measurement.

If you want to measure a single character, say `x`, you can use the expandable

```
\fontcharwd\font`x
```

For instance, the width of “x” in the current font, expressed as an integer representing scaled points, you can do

```
\number\fontcharwd\font`x
```

For the length in points, just do

```
\the\fontcharwd\font`x
```

Comment: Perhaps this should start with the idea of expansion?